# How to change time formats in python?

Tags: python, string, time

How do i get the following list

```
 [datetime.date(2011, 4, 1), datetime.date(2011, 4, 8), datetime.date(2011, 4, 16), datetime.date(2011, 5, 21)]
```

as

```
['2011-04','2011-05']
```

It not only convert to string but remove dups

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the dates to strings using [datetime.date.strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).

```
dates = [date.strftime('%Y-%m') for date in dates]
```

You can remove duplicates by converting the list to a set and then back to a list.

```
dates = list(set(dates))
```

Then combine both methods to do it all in one step.

```
dates = list(set([date.strftime('%Y-%m') for date in dates]))
```

Comment: I first need to change the dates to string....otherwise the days are all different

Comment: @user428862 I was getting there. Patience. ;)

Comment: The set module was deprecated because with 2.6 it was made a built-in class. So, it is even more a part of Python.

Comment: @judge...as a newbie...deprecated means out...So, in 2.7 and 3.1 I can use set. correct...

Comment: @user428862 Yes, you can continue to use set. To reiterate, the set class was not deprecated. It used to be in separate module, but was moved into Python proper. So, the old module was deprecated and not the set class itself.

Comment: using: dates= list(set([date.strftime('%Y-%m') for date in dates])) I dont like map, it does not like me.. :-)

Comment: @user428862 A list comprehension would definitely perform better in this case because of the lambda function. I removed the map version.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> dates = [datetime.date(2011, 4, 1), datetime.date(2011, 4, 8), datetime.date(2011, 4, 16), datetime.date(2011, 5, 21)]
>>> set([date.strftime('%Y-%m') for date in dates])
set(['2011-05', '2011-04'])
```

`set` turns a list into a set object, removing duplicates. The `[date.strftime('%Y-%m') for date in dates]` is a list comprehension that turns each date into a string using the `strftime` function with a year-month pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [43]: import datetime

In [44]: dates=[datetime.date(2011, 4, 1), datetime.date(2011, 4, 8), datetime.date(2011, 4, 16), datetime.date(2011, 5, 21)]

In [45]: set([date.strftime('%Y-%m') for date in dates])
Out[45]: set(['2011-04', '2011-05'])
```