# Convert list of datetime.datetime variables

Tags: python, matlab, datetime

I have a list of variable that includes several `datetime.datetime` type variables.

I.e.:

```
a['PrTimeStamp']    # Type list
[0] datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 19, 10, 0)  # Type datetime
[1] datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 3, 12, 0)   # Type datetime
[2] datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 4, 0, 0)    # Type datetime
[3] datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 10, 13, 0)  # Type datetime
[4] datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 16, 20, 0)  # Type datetime
[5] datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 17, 2, 0)   # Type datetime
```

E.g. if I make `print(a['PrTimeStamp'][0])` it prints to screen: `2014-10-19 10:00:00`.

Now I want to convert this list to a format that can be easily read by matlab. 
I tried to do the following:

```
a['PrTimeStamp'] = a['PrTimeStamp'].strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

But I got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
date[]
for i in a['PrTimeStamp']:
    date.append(i.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
```

a must be a **dictionary** has a key **PrTimeStamp**

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need `data.strftime` to format the dates. Something similar to this.

[How to change time formats in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513922/how-to-change-time-formats-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Since a['PrTimeStamp'] is a list of date time objects, you need to iterate each item in the list and format the date time object in it!

Since you haven't posted the entire code,

```
a={}
import datetime
a['PrTimeStamp']  = [ datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 19, 10, 0)
, datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 3, 12, 0)
, datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 4, 0, 0)
, datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 10, 13, 0)
, datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 16, 20, 0)
, datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 17, 2, 0)]
#this is what you need!
print [ts.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S") for ts in a['PrTimeStamp']]
```

will print

```
['19-Oct-2014 10:00:00', '03-Dec-2014 12:00:00', '04-Dec-2014 00:00:00', '10-Dec-2014 13:00:00', '16-Dec-2014 20:00:00', '17-Dec-2014 02:00:00']
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry not very clear how do I redefine the variable a['PrTimeStamp'] to be "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S" ... 

I guess I can't do the following:
[a['PrTimeStamp'] = ts.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S") for ts in a['PrTimeStamp']]

Comment: I've given the sample output! Did that answer your question?